# Is BIND9 what I'm looking for?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, debian-wheezy

I just purchased a dedicated server and have Debian 7 installed. I of course want my server to work with my domain, so I assume what I need to do is install BIND9 on the dedicated server and configure it properly?

Or is BIND9 completely irrelevant (a.k.a.: would I just go ahead and point my domain, which is registered on another host, to my server)? I tried researching it a bit, but I'm fairly new to the server world and just wanted to confirm here.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, I'd use a third-party DNS service. There are plenty of free (or very cheap) options out there.

Comment: Do you mind giving me some personal recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: The free DNS service provided by most domain registrars is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind9 is for serving DNS records for an entire domain, not just a single server. The company that set you up with

```
myserver.com
```

is likely doing all the DNS work you need. The people that need to run BIND generally know they need to run BIND since you have to register your DNS domain with the next level up servers. If you don't know what that means, you likely don't need to run a nameserver.